# SQL Separate hours in Start and EndDate

Tags: sql

I'm need a help to create a Query. My problem is I have a StartDate and EndDate and need separate this in blocs of 60 minutes.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS SMALLDATETIME

SET @STARTDATE = '2012-11-21 11:03:00'
SET @ENDDATE = '2012-11-21 13:04:00'
```

I need the return:

```
Hour, Time
11  , 57
12  , 60
13  , 04
```

Comment: You may want to have your desired output actually match your example `@startdate` and `@enddate` times. Also, what is the `time` column? Minutes or seconds doesn't make sense with **60** as an example.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: LittleBobbyTables, I think it does match.  He doesn't want timestamps, he wants the number of minutes between the dates.  11,57 means 57 minutes remaining until 12:00

Comment: Coelho, what do you want to return if the startdate or enddate is exactly on the hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive CTE.  For example:

```
declare @startDate datetime = '2012-11-21 22:05:00'
declare @endDate datetime = '2012-11-22 01:06:00'

; with  TimeList as
        (
        select  @startDate as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(hour, 1, dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dt), 0))
        from    TimeList
        where   dateadd(hour, 1, dt) < @endDate
        )
select  dt
from    TimeList
union all
select  @endDate
```

The snippet `dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dt), 0)` removes the hours and minutes from a date.  It does so by calculating the number of hours since date `0` and then adding that number of hours to date `0`.

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/1044/0)

Answer (score 0):

I unsure if i understood you but this will return the hour and minute after your start date at 60 min intervals.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS SMALLDATETIME

DECLARE @time AS TABLE(id int identity(1,1), [hour] int, [time] int)

SET @STARTDATE = '2012-11-21 11:03:00'
SET @ENDDATE = '2012-11-21 13:04:00'

WHILE @STARTDATE < @ENDDATE
BEGIN
    SELECT @STARTDATE = DATEADD(MINUTE,60,@STARTDATE)
    INSERT INTO @time (hour,time)
    VALUES(DATEPART(HOUR,@STARTDATE),DATEPART(MINUTE,@STARTDATE))
END

SELECT * FROM @time
```

Comment: Good start, but the in-between hours have to be rounded.  I.e. `13:00` not `13:03`.  The enddate should also be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You coan do it in three pieces.  First piece is for the first hour, 60 minus the minute value, 2nd piece is time=60 for all hours between start+1 and end, third piece is end minutes

and then insert them into a temp table, as abstractChaos has done.

Insert into temp table like AbstractChaos:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE AS SMALLDATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE AS SMALLDATETIME

DECLARE @TIME AS TABLE(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), [HOUR] INT, [TIME] INT)

SET @STARTDATE = '2012-11-21 11:03:00'
SET @ENDDATE = '2012-11-21 13:04:00'

INSERT INTO @TIME (HOUR,TIME) 
VALUES (datepart(HOUR,@startdate) ,60 - datepart(MINUTE,@startdate) )

WHILE @STARTDATE < @ENDDATE
BEGIN
    SELECT @STARTDATE = DATEADD(MINUTE,60,@STARTDATE)
    INSERT INTO @TIME (HOUR,TIME) 
    VALUES(datepart(HOUR,@STARTDATE) , 60) 
END

INSERT INTO @TIME (HOUR,TIME) 
VALUES(datepart(HOUR,@enddate) , datepart(MINUTE,@startdate))
```

Comment: -1 You can't use `while` as part of a union.  It wouldn't even parse.